# Ubuntu 13.04, Atheros AR9287 ath9k driver, airmon-ng fixed on channel -1

Tags: 13.04, aircrack-ng

`airmon-ng` was working fine out of the box with Ubuntu 12.10, but after upgrade, `mon0` is `fixed on channel -1`.

I am using kernel 3.8.0-25-generic.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: anyone having the same problem?

Comment: Exact duplicate of: [How can I solve “fixed channel -1” (mon0 is on channel -1) issue when using airodump-ng?](http://askubuntu.com/q/318583/52726)