# How can I solve "fixed channel -1" (mon0 is on channel -1) issue when using airodump-ng?

Tags: wireless, aircrack-ng

I am beginner in Ubuntu 12.04, and have a problem with *aircrack-ng*. `airodump-ng` gived me a `fixed channel -1` error. The access point is on channel 5, but I can't switch to that channel because of that error.

My hardware is: Broadcom BCM431, driver *b43*. I've tried patching,  but had a problem with driver installation.

Comment: mmm What exactly do you need?

Comment: What is the problem? Did you get an *error*?

Comment: @Lucio the problen is in the title but I have never seeen this with Ubuntu(nor did I find anything on it) but I do find this message related to backtrack(though the solutions I see that are for backtrack are not clear to me how they relate to Ubuntu).

Comment: I don't understand your message. Are you saying that you get the same error than @Mr.lalala?

Comment: Sir I use the option --ignore-negative-one in aireplay-ng it works but I am not getting WPA handshake to crack the WPA key please give solution for this

Answer (score 12):

Download and install the latest Aircrack-ng development (beta). There's an `--ignore-negative-one` switch that you can use to fix that `fixed channel -1` annoying error.

Here's how you can install the latest Aircrack-ng.
Type the following commands in a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

1. `sudo apt-get install subversion libnl-dev`
2. `cd /opt/`
3. `sudo svn co http://svn.aircrack-ng.org/trunk/ aircrack-ng`
4. `cd aircrack-ng`
5. `sudo make`
6. `sudo make install`

Once it's done, run `aircrack-ng` without any options, and look at the first line, it should read something like this:

```
Aircrack-ng 1.2 beta1 r2312 - (C) 2006-2013 Thomas d'Otreppe
```

Now, when you use `airodump-ng` and `aireplay-ng`, always use the option `--ignore-negative-one`.

Comment: If sudo make gives errors you may also need to run `sudo apt install libssl-dev libnl-3-dev libnl-genl-3-dev`. See https://cseverson.com/docs/severson-wifi-hacking.pdf

Comment: @NULL I still get "pkg-config not found" / "Cannot find development files for any supported version of libnl" :(