# How to install compat-drivers?

Tags: drivers, compiling, aircrack-ng, compat-wireless

I followed many many tutorials but it doesn't work. I want to install the `compat-drivers` which include the `negative-one-patch`. In `airodump-ng` I always get the error:
`mon0 is on channel -1, but the AP uses channel...`

I tried many OS, like Ubuntu 13.04, 12.04/10 and Neptune 3.1 from ZevenOS. I also tried BackTrack but it doesn't boot.

The only thing I want is to install succesfully the `compat-drivers`.

If so, could anyone help me, it would be very nice! Thank you very much!

Comment: Not trying to answer your problem, not asking for information, but you might want to install Kali Linux instead Backtrack.

Comment: Install the latest `aircrack-ng` instead of installing `compat-drivers`, it has a fix for the negative one thing. To install the latest `aircrack-ng`, see my answer here: [How can I solve “fixed channel -1” (mon0 is on channel -1) issue when using airodump-ng?](http://askubuntu.com/q/318583/52726) Possible duplicate.