# Aircrack 1.1 do not get installed

Tags: installation, aircrack-ng

I have installed the Aircrack-NG 1.3 BETA. I realized that the program airmon is missing. After this i installed Aircrack-NG 1.1 with "make install". For some reason the binaries do not get copied into the /usr/local/bin folder. But i can find some files with the executalbe names inside /user/local/man. How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
    sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng
```

Answer (score 0):

Go back and install Aircrack-NG 1.3 BETA. The command to use `airmon` is `airmon-ng`.

```
alaa@aa-u:~/TestFolder$ sudo airmon-ng --help

usage: airmon-ng <start|stop|check> <interface> [channel or frequency]
```

If it still doesn't work, install the aircrack suite using the steps in my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/322468/52726